# Write php form input to a file outside document root

Tags: php, html

I am collecting a few bits of information through a html form, which passes it onto a php file, which writes it to a simple text file.  The problem is this only works if the php and the resulting text file are all in publicly visible document root.

Obviously I would like to keep the text file outside the document root. I tried a proxy solution where a php file in document root simply includes the real php file in a secret location.  Unfortunately this does not work (no input file found).

The html form is in `~/www-root/php/form.html`.  It calls the following php file.  Web server error: file not found.

The php file (`~/secret/process.php`)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $data1 = $_POST['name'] . "\n";

    $ret = file_put_contents('store_info.txt', $data1, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't care about the web server root directory.  Make sure the user running PHP has permissions to the file and share your code and any error messages.

Comment: Can't you just use the `../` parent directory?

Comment: @Devon, I am on a shared host, so I am not sure what permissions I will need to set on these files.  Is it possible to get 'file not found' error due to permissions?